# JqGrid Basic Grid example error when saving a new row

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the Basic Grid example from [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#t24):

```
jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid(
        {
            url : 'clientArray',
            datatype : "local",
            colNames : [ 'Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax',
                    'Total', 'Notes' ],
            colModel : [ {
                name : 'id',
                index : 'id',
                width : 55,
                editable : true,
                key: true
            }, {
                name : 'invdate',
                index : 'invdate',
                width : 90,
                editable : true
            }, {
                name : 'name',
                index : 'name',
                width : 100,
                editable : true
            }, {
                name : 'amount',
                index : 'amount',
                width : 80,
                align : "right",
                editable : true
            }, {
                name : 'tax',
                index : 'tax',
                width : 80,
                align : "right",
                editable : true
            }, {
                name : 'total',
                index : 'total',
                width : 80,
                align : "right",
                editable : true
            }, {
                name : 'note',
                index : 'note',
                width : 150,
                sortable : false,
                editable : true
            } ],
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
            pager : '#prowed1',
            sortname : 'id',
            viewrecords : true,
            sortorder : "desc",
            editurl : "clientArray",
            caption : "Basic Example"
        });
jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('navGrid', "#prowed1", {
    edit : false,
    add : false,
    del : false
});
```

The following events to handle the user clicks on edit, save, and cancel buttons:

```
jQuery("#ed1").click(function() {
    var id = jQuery('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('editRow', id);
    this.disabled = 'true';
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled", false);
});
jQuery("#sved1").click(function() {

    var rowid = jQuery('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    alert('id: ' + rowid);
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('saveRow', rowid , false );
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery("#ed1").attr("disabled", false);
    jQuery("#aded1").attr("disabled", false);
    
});
jQuery("#cned1").click(function() {
    var id = jQuery('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('restoreRow', id);
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery("#ed1").attr("disabled", false);
    jQuery("#aded1").attr("disabled", false);
});

jQuery("#aded1").click(function() {
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('addRow',  'new');
    this.disabled = 'true';
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

And the html of the buttons:

```
 <input type="BUTTON" id="aded1"  value="Add Row" />
 <input type="BUTTON" id="ed1" value="Edit row 3" /> 
 <input type="BUTTON" id="sved1" disabled='true' value="Save row 3" /> 
 <input type="BUTTON" id="cned1" disabled='true' value="Cancel Save" />
```

But the grid is not working properly because:

- After saving a new row it keeps selected and I can't select others.
- When I cancel the editing of a row, it deletes a few other rows.
- When I click for second time
  the add new row button, google chrome debugger console displays the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

I am almost sure that it has something to do with the new row id, but after 2 days of trying I  would appreciate a little help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong parameters to `addRow`. From the [jqGrid documentation for `addRow`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#addrow):

> Calling convention:
>
> ```
> jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('addRow',parameters);
> ```
>
> where parameters is a object and has the following default values:
>
> ```
> parameters =
> {
>   rowID : "new_row",
>   initdata : {},
>   position :"first",
>   useDefValues : false,
>   useFormatter : false,
>   addRowParams : {extraparam:{}}
> }
> ```

Also, you will want to set `rowID` equal to a new value each time. You can either do this explicitly or you can set it to `undefined` to let jqGrid assign a random ID to each new row.

---

For example:

```
jQuery("#aded1").click(function() { 
    var parameters = { 
          rowid : undefined, 
          initdata : {}, 
          position :"first", 
          useDefValues : false, 
          useFormatter : false, 
          addRowParams : {extraparam:{}} 
    };

    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('addRow', parameters); 
});
```

Comment: Thnks Justin. Still is only adding correctly the first row, then i try to add a new one and is not saved. I try to use undefined but I dont quite understand where to use it, I set rowid:undefined but it didn't work..

Comment: **To add new Row:** `jQuery("#aded1").click(function() {
  parameters =
  {
    rowid : "new_row",
    initdata : {},
    position :"first",
    useDefValues : false,
    useFormatter : false,
    addRowParams : {extraparam:{}}
  }
  jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('addRow',  parameters);
 });`  **For saving:** `jQuery("sved1").click(function() {
  
  var rowid = jQuery('#rowed1').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
  jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('saveRow', rowid); 
 });`

Comment: I updated my answer; please see the example code at the bottom.

Comment: Also, if you're interested, this post explains a bit more about using `undefined` to generate row ID's: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078650/jqgrid-always-highlighting-first-row-when-using-addrowdata

Comment: No, thats what I did earlier (when I try to use the undefined property) and I got an error that says "rowid is not defined". I think the problem is when I save the record. How does jquery to know the rowid when I pass it as parameter inthe save function `jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('saveRow', rowid);`?